# Access_ Dined reseller3.0 - RapidReseller

Tags: python, google-api, google-reseller-api

I see the code in github https://github.com/google/enterprise-deployments/tree/master/apps/python/reseller3.0/RapidReseller,

and I try implement for see manage my reseller domain, but I have some problems.

I have :

INFO     2014-11-14 14:36:56,663 client.py:680] Refreshing access_token
INFO     2014-11-14 14:36:57,603 client.py:699] Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested client not authorized."
}

File "/home/eduduarte/Downloads/ApisGoogle/google_appengine1.915/revenda/oauth2client/client.py", line 710, in _do_refresh_request
    raise AccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg)
AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied

I created the key, the enable of Api, do download of key to the app, and too I use my account super admin: in settings.py RESELLER_ADMIN, and I have "access_denied"

Please, can someone help me.

Eduardo Duarte

Answer (score 0):

Did you also added the scopes in the Admin Console for the clientID of your application?

In the Admin Console https://admin.google.com go to Security > Advanced Settings > In the Authentication section go to "Manage API client access". In the "Client Name" textbox write the clientID of your app and in the "One or More API Scopes" add the next scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.order
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification
- https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

this is done so the domain grant the app access to the information.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend checking out the codelab that we just posted.  We just posted samples in four languages that walk through the entire end-to-end process of provisioning a resold customer.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/codelab/intro